# what did I do wrong (javascript object) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
var map = {
    columns: 25,
    rows: 12,
    size: calculateElementSize(),
    elements: function(){
        var elements = [];
        for(i = 0; i < this.columns; i++){
            elements[i] = [];
            for(j = 0; j < this.rows; j++){
                elements[i][j] = {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    type: "basicElement",
                    status: 1
                }
            }
        }
    return elements;
    }
}
console.log(map.elements[0][0].x);
```

I meant to do an array of objects inside map object, any ideas what I did wrong? Thanks in advance ;d

Comment: where is you function calculateElementSize()

Comment: Also, declare `i` and `j` with `let` or `var` inside that function

Comment: function calculateElementSize(){
    //viewport height width
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    
    width /= 100; // 1vw
    height /= 100; // 1vh
    
    width = Math.round(width);
    height = Math.round(height);
    
    width *= 3; 
    height *= 3;
    
    return width > height ? width : height;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from not having any code for calculateElementSize(), I could get the value for 0,0 using:

```js
    var map = {
        columns: 25,
        rows: 12,
        //size: calculateElementSize(),
        elements: [],
        createElements: function(){
            var xelements = [];
            for(i = 0; i < this.columns; i++){
                xelements[i] = [];
                for(j = 0; j < this.rows; j++){
                    xelements[i][j] = {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        type: "basicElement",
                        status: 1
                    }
                }
            }
          this.elements = xelements;
        },
        getElement: function(c, r) {
          return this.elements[c][r];
        }
    }
    map.createElements();
    console.log(map.getElement(0,0));
```

The elements array is created by the createElements() function and the getElement() function gets the column/row item (assuming I have column and row the right way around)

Comment: Thanks you very much, that what i was looking for :d

Comment: @NieNoSpoko You might want to double-check that I have the `c` and `r` parameters the right way around.  Test this by setting the `x` and `y` values in the inner loop to the values of i and j and confirm that this is reading the right element.  Then, once the getElement() call has been made (in my final line of code), you can extract any part of it you need.

Comment: I checked it out, it works as I wanted, thank you again :)

Comment: well, I don't know how

Answer (score 4):

console.log(map.elements()[0][0].x);
You declared elements as function, but you did not invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Elements is a function as such you can't read it as an array.
If it returned (with an explicit return elements in the elements function) elements, map.elements()[0][0].x might return something but likely not what you want.

What do you exactly expect to do with this map object?

Comment: well im going to build game using squares, so it's going to store their coords.

Comment: var mapElements = [];
    for(i = 0; i < mapElementColumn; i++){
            mapElements[i] = [];
        for(j = 0; j < mapElementRow; j++){
            mapElements[i][j] = {x:0, y:0, elementType: "mapElement", status: 1};
        }    
    }

Comment: it was my original idea, but now i decided to keep all "mapElement" variables inside 1 object.

Comment: If map is your initial elements, just create the elements object aside and define map={many properties..., elements: some elements defined somewhere else} then on updates depending on your framework you could do map={...map,elements: newElementsObject}